# Custom color in keywordstyle for listings under LyX

Tags: listings, color, lyx, keywords

There are several Questions and Answers regarding the use of listings under LyX. And they mention, or explain, how to enable syntax highlighting. While this is easy to achieve, my attempt to use a custom color (defined in the Preamble) for *keywords*, fails.

For example, I would like to use the color `\definecolor{grassgis}{rgb}{8, 150, 13}` within the Listings settings (LyX: Document > Settings > Listings). It appears as white!

[image]

Using any of the *conventional* colors, like *magenta* works fine.

[image]

**Why is this happening? Where should the custom color definition be placed?**

Comment: Use `\definecolor{grassgis}{RGB}{8, 150, 13}` instead of `\definecolor{grassgis}{rgb}{8, 150, 13}` (note the uppercase). With the former, the range of color values is [0,255], whereas, with the latter, the range is [0,1].

Comment: Would you like to convert this to an answer? That was it!

Comment: Sure, we can close this as a duplicate if there is already one. So far, I didn't see any... rgb vs RGB and lyx and listings.